# How to use Job Import Plugin in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using one Jenkins setup/instance to run the smoke tests (i.e using this Jenkins for QA only). Now I have to use another Jenkins job url in my first instance. The purpose is after successful code staging (on Dev Jenkins) it should automatically trigger the smoke tests (on QA Jenkins).

I know that Job import plugin can be used to achieve this but I am not sure as in where exactly to configure it. Googled it as well but unable to find anything.

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why do you think the job import plugin is a good choice here?  Why wouldn't you set up a job on the second machine once and use a trigger when the first job is done to run it?

Comment: I would have done that if I had access to Dev Jenkins. Unfortunately I don't have access to it and hence this simple idea will not work here. :)

Comment: Manage Jenkins => Configure System => Remote Jenkins server configurations. Found an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56061186/72717

Answer (score 1):

Just import the Job Import plugin, restart Jenkins and then access the plugin on your browser using the URL:
< Jenkins URL >/job-import

For Ex: http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job-import

If you get an error page here, cross-check whether plugin installation was successful or not. This won't work until all the dependent plugins are get installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a HTTP access to the DEV machine, maybe you can use the URL trigger plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/URLTrigger+Plugin

And trigger the last successful build number URL:

```
http://YOUR_JENKINS_SERVER/job/YOUR_JOB/lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber
```

If you don't have any access between your QA and DEV machines, it will be hard to trigger a job ;)

Answer (score 0):

Download Jenkins JAR file

Go to location where JAR is located and enter following command

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/jenkins/ -auth admin:password create-job UploadToReleases < C:\Users\admin\UploadtoReleases.xml
```

`create-job` is command to import a job.
`create-job` always required name of jenkins job followed by `< filename`