# How to use job import plugin in jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I don't have access to both servers so cli is not an option only jenkins ui is available. I need to import jobs using job import plugin but i am unable to figure how to configure the plugin so as to import jobs. Could anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To configure the Jenkins Remote Plugin, you need to add a **Jenkins Server** to import your jobs.

#### Setting a Jenkins Server

To add a Jenkins Server, you need to go on your Jenkins configuration: `Manage Jenkins` > `Configure System` > `Job Import Plugin` or `http://jenkins-host:port/configure` and add the Url and credentials to the host from where will import the jobs.

[image]

If you don't have, will need to add the credentials to this server, to do this click on the option **Add** bellow the Url settings.

[image]

#### Using the Jenkins Import plugin

After setting a Jenkins server, you will be able to use the Jenkins Import plugin by going to option `Job Import Plugin` in the Jenkins home or going to the URL: `http://jenkins-host:port/Job-import/` or `http://jenkins-host:port/job-import/` in the new versions.

If you added only a Jenkins Server it will be selected as default, otherwise, the correct Jenkins server will need to be selected:

[image]

Normally you don't need to set the **Remote folder** or **Search into folders** options, so if you use the default Jenkins settings, leave these fields blank.

Then, you will click on the **Query!** button, to start your import. A page with all jobs available to be imported will be showed.

You will need to select all the jobs you want to import one by one, if you have many jobs (like in my case) this can be a little boring. A good idea is to select the **Install required plugins** option too.

[image]

After select everything, you can click on the **Import!** button to finally starts your import.

Comment: I have this all set up but it's not pulling any folders, whether I select "search into subfolders", enter a folder name, or any combination of those. Where should I check for an error?

Comment: @MaxCascone you should take a look on Jenkins' error log  file. Normally on `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`. For more information about the Jenkins logging take a look on  https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=37323361#content/view/37323361

Comment: What about credentials and other plugin configurations (if we choose to install plugin)?

Comment: This is cool, I am able to import all my jobs. Thanks for detailed steps.

Comment: @valdeci Done !

Comment: The import URL is `http://jenkins-host:port/job-import/` (lowercase 'j') here with Jenkins 2.289.3.

Comment: @valdeci, you're aware there's no documentation for this plugin but your answer fills the gap. You indicate "*Normally you don't need to set the Remote folder or Search into folders options*". Folders are a popular configuration (+220K installs).  Somewhere between  Jenkins 1.121.3, plus job-import-plugin-3.3,folders-6.5.1 and Jenkins-2.289.3, with job-import-plugin-3.4,folders-6.16, the plugin behaviour broke for folders. I have [Answered this Q to elaborate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68799939/598141). Perhaps you can reference in your answer for completeness until there's better docs?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to import jobs using UI -

1. You need to install job import plugin on the server where you need to
   import jobs to.
2. Then go to the plugin displayed on left side of jenkins.
3. Enter url and authentication and jobs will be listed of remote server.
4. Select the jobs to be copied and done. Jenkins will copy the jobs to your server.

[Refer this link](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+Import+Plugin)

Comment: Since version 3.0 of the plugin, the URL and the authentication details need to be configured in the Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Remote Jenkins server configurations.

Comment: Thanks @coz . I couldn't figure out what I was missing. That's just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting below error (401 Unauthorized) the username:password configuration worked only after setting a new API token on a the source jenkins instance and using it as 'password' in the target instance credentials. Pretty much all other answers cover the configuration of the plugin.

```
Failed to list job from remote http://{remoteIP}:8080/. Response status code received 401. Content: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401 Unauthorized</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/api/xml</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>401</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Unauthorized</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>Stapler</td></tr>
</table>
<hr/><a href="https://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.45.v20220203</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

Also if wondering where to check logs, it's `http://<your_jenkins_ip/domain>:8080/logs/all`